# When synchronizing my report with Teamleader I get a itgensql001 error for a custom field

Tags: invantive-sql, invantive-control, teamleader

When synching my Teamleader report in Invantive Control I get the following error:

```
Unknown identifier 'cpyd.c_5_contactpersoon'.
```

Screenshot of error

[image]

Part of the query:

```
select pjtd.pjt_title          pjt_title
,      cpyd.c_5_contactpersoon customer_contact_person
```

This is a custom field in Teamleader.

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: Maybe good plan to add more details on the query?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a custom field in Teamleader, the order of the fields will change.

In order to check which new number is assigned to certain fields, you can execute the following query:

```
select * from Teamleader.CustomFields.Custom_Fields_All
```

This will return a list of all the custom fields, with the number that is assigned to them.

For example:

[image: teamleader custom field]

So the custom field 'contactpersoon' will be 6 in this case.

This means the number of the field in the query has to be changed:

```
cpyd.c_5_contactpersoon > cpyd.c_6_contactpersoon
```

Comment: Teamleader has no code for a custom field, just a label. When the label is changed, the custom field name changes too.